# Unable to read properties using @Value in SpringBoot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

So I have the following structure

```
@Component 
@RequiredArgsConstructor
ClassA{
    ClassB b = new ClassB();
    b.printTableName(); 
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
ClassB{
  @Value("${com.table}")
  private String tableName;
  
  public printTableName(){
    System.out.println(tableName);
  }
}
```

---

The printTableName function always prints null , the tableName in this function is always null . How do I go about fixing this ?

Thank you for the help !

Comment: ` public printTableName(){
    System.out.println(tableName);
  }` what is the return type of this function? Invalid declaration I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot instance the class manually if you need the spring manage your beans.

Try instance your beans with spring injects

```java
@Component
public class ClassB {

    @Value("${com.table1}")
    private String valueRequiredOnProperties;

    @Value("${com.table2:#{null}}")
    private String valueNullByDefaultIfNotInformedOnProperties;
    
    @Value("${com.table3:table_default}")
    private String valueByDefaultTableIfNotInformedOnProperties;
    
    
    public void printTableName(){
        System.out.println(valueRequiredOnProperties);
        System.out.println(valueNullByDefaultIfNotInformedOnProperties);
        System.out.println(valueByDefaultTableIfNotInformedOnProperties);
    }

}



@Component
public class ClassA { // you need call this class in controllers, configurations or others ways to spring manager the instances

    // it's necessary indicate to spring manage the instance of beans
    @Autowired
    private ClassB classBManagedBySpring;

    public void callPrintClassB(){
    
        ClassB classB = new ClassB();
        
        classBManagedBySpring.printTableName(); // this will work
        classB.printTableName(); // this will not work
    
    }

}
```

your application.properties

```
com.table1=TABELA_1
# com.table2=
# com.table3=
```