# Set environment property in yaml using placeholder

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, spring-el

I have a map `propMap`, set as a PropertySource in the Environment object in my Spring Boot application. What would be the correct notation to access a key in the map from the .yaml file?

I tried using `username: "#{propMap.['username']}"` but doesn't seem to work. I tried few others too but didn't help. Could I know what would be the correct expression I could use in this case?

Thank you

Comment: I think this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/68012617/7505687

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a map property source to the environment, every key-value pair in the map becomes a property in the environment. The property's name is the key from the map and the property’s value is the value from the map. You can then use `${property-name}` to refer to the property and its value. For example, if your map contains the key `username` with the value `alice`, the property placeholder `${username}` will resolve to `alice`.

Comment: You are a gem @Andy. Thanks a lot for the wisdom